# Covariance matrix from factor loadings and factor covariances?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, matrix-multiplication

I have a list of 6 assets with loading vectors on 4 factors, and I have the covariance matrix for the 4 factors. How can I build a 6x6 "asset" covariance matrix using these two inputs?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
## Python 2.7
```

Loading vectors:

```
raw_asset_loadings = {'asset1': [.25, .25, .25, .25], 
              'asset2': [.0, 0,.5,.5], 
              'asset3': [0,0,1.25,.25], 
              'asset4': [0,0,.25,0], 
              'asset5': [.85,0,0,.15],
              'asset6': [.7,.15,0,.15]}
asset_loadings = pd.DataFrame(data=raw_asset_loadings)
```

which yields

```
    asset1  asset2  asset3  asset4  asset5  asset6
  0 0.25    0.0     0.00    0.00    0.85    0.70
  1 0.25    0.0     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.15
  2 0.25    0.5     1.25    0.25    0.00    0.00
  3 0.25    0.5     0.25    0.00    0.15    0.15
```

and factor covariance matrix:

```
raw_cov = {0: [.04, .008, .12, .0], 
       1: [.008, .01,.0015,0], 
       2: [.0012,.0015,.0036,.0], 
       3: [.0,.0,.0,.0004]}
factor_cov = pd.DataFrame(data=raw_cov)
```

which yields

```
    0       1       2       3
0   0.040   0.0080  0.0012  0.0000
1   0.008   0.0100  0.0015  0.0000
2   0.120   0.0015  0.0036  0.0000
3   0.000   0.0000  0.0000  0.0004
```

I thought this would work, but I get a 4x6 matrix, not the desired 6x6 matrix:

```
covy = (np.matmul(np.matmul(asset_loadings.T,factor_cov),factor_cov))
```

any ideas on how to create a 6x6 from the 4 factors?

Answer (score 1):

was multiplying by the wrong term at the end. Answer is:

```
covy = (np.matmul(np.matmul(asset_loadings.T,factor_cov),asset_loadings))
```

first post to stackoverflow and of course i get my own answer 10 minutes later after stepping out for coffee....